# Ionic + Phonegap - add offline database with authorization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, cordova, ionic-framework

I've recently made simple app using ionic framework (also with phonegap android/ios). I needed to store some user data in database. I found out about firebase and successfully integrated it in my app. I've let user log in anonymously or by google. In my case each user should see only his content so I've added rules - and they work. However my app needs to run without internet connection on mobile platforms (android/ios) and firebase doesn't provide full offline storage (only temponary) in javascript (persistent storage is for now implemented in native only). So basically I hit the wall. I've been told about CouchDB/PouchDB and it indeed support offline storage and sync with remote server. I've created an account on cloudant, but then I remembered I need user authorization - as I said user needs to have only his own data. So let's say guest have only local database and user logged in with google have database also on remote server so he can switch device and work with the same (his own) data. But I can't find such tool in CouchDB (cloudant). Is there any other solution, which works with ionic smoothly and provides:

- offline database,
- authorization with google,
- remote database with sync (with local db) after successful authorization,
- remote database is hosted on some server (may be paid, but trial needed) - i don't want to worry about server - client only

?

TL;DR: I'm looking for a hosting service working on ionic/angularjs/cordova with remote database + local database and synchronisation between them.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with using MongoDB it is by far the easiest to integrate with Express/Node.js using the npm mongoose. It's really popular and great way to store data and its similar to firebase.
For example:

```
var Express = require('express'),
app = Express.router();
app.route('/api/auth/signup').post(users.signup);
```

Schema Example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill in your first name'//message given if you fail to provide the required field.
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill in your last name'
  },
  displayName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: 'Email already exists. Sign In?',
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    default: '',
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyEmail, 'Please fill a valid email address'],//create a custom Email Validation strategy
    required: 'Please enter a valid business Email'
  },
});
```

Sample Controller:

```
exports.signup = function (req, res) {
  // For security measurement we remove the roles from the req.body object
  delete req.body.roles;

  // Init user and add missing fields
  var user = new User(req.body);
  user.provider = 'local';
  user.displayName = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;

  // Then save the user
  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      // Remove sensitive data before login
      user.password = undefined;
      user.salt = undefined;

      var jwtToken = authentication.signToken(user);
      res.json({ user: user, token: jwtToken });
    }
  });
};
```

You can find some of this on MEAN.js Github.
But you must use LocalStorage. JSON web tokens for your ionic app if you want it to work on an iPad/iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Does it mean I have to create server-side (setting up database, authorization) as well? I don't know express and never worked with mongoDB, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately if you are wanting to locally store stuff in a database I find it unlikely->impossible that you'll be able to do that without a fairly simple server. Node.js is a great choice for a simple server. I think you can lookup simple Mongoose examples but you know you basically have to get a password, an email and send those to a certain URL using $http.post('/api/auth/signup', {email: $scope.field.email, password: $scope.field.password}) then the Express.router() will accept it on the /api/auth/signup route it will be available in the req (req is short for request) req.body;

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to use [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) which works with local storage (works on ionic/cordova) and will sync to a remote couchdb server with just a few lines of code:

```
var localDB = new PouchDB('mylocaldb');
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/myremotedb');
localDB.sync(remoteDB);
```

The only tricky bit is the remote server with authentication. CouchDB can handle oauth out of the box, but on a per-database case, meaning you need to create a database per user, which is what many people do, but that's quite involved. Do a  [search for CouchDB on npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=couchdb) and see what comes up.

Alternatively, you can wrap your CouchDB behind a node server like Express, and handle auth in Express before passing the requests through.

It's not an easy task, and there's a reason Firebase charges a small fortune once you start racking up usage. If you're not big on server-side stuff, a simpler approach might be to use [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) or [hoodie](http://hood.ie/).